# reinitialize an app after reopen it

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

I am wondering for a background running app, is there a way to reinitialize the app (like terminate the app and start the app from the beginning) when I reopen the app after a long time of suspension? I think the OS would kill the app when the device is out of memory, so can I do this manually?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: One reason is to make sure the user always get the new data, but if I update the data without terminate it, the app may become unstable. The other reason is to avoid memory leak.

Comment: If you are doing this to avoid a memory leak then you are failing the 1st part of app design. Create a quality app that utilizes proper memory management and you will never have that issue. Use the method I posted to update any data on load if it goes stale.

Comment: That pretty much sounds like you don't have a valid reason to terminate the app besides working around some bugs in your code. You should definitely invest into learning to use the debugger and instruments.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to make an old app to support multi-tasking, I would not be able to "redesign" it. I have to find a way which does not cost too much.

Answer (score 0):

No, well at not officially. Technically you could abort() the app but it's strongly discouraged to ever do that. If you're wanting to reinitialize something in your app then just do so from within the...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```